# JSF: How to propagate params to login page in web.xml

Tags: java, jsf, web.xml

I've a page like:

```
/myApp/internalPage.xhtml?orderId=1234
```

When user is not logged, my web.xml configuration redirect to

```
/myApp/login.xhtml
```

In this step, I loose my params information (orderId=1234).

*How can I configure web.xml to propagate all params to login page?*

I want to be redirected to:

```
/myApp/login.xhtml?orderId=1234
```

Tks

Comment: I think you manually need to create re-direct url by appending params.

Comment: you can create a Filter (javax.servlet.Filter) that checks if there is a login user, and if none then redirect it to /myApp/login.xhtml with your parameters.

Comment: @jay: No, you can't. Filters are not invoked at all when the container managed security check hasn't passed. The login page is displayed directly by the container without invoking any of the filters.

Comment: thanks @BalusC :) so, what do you suggest to achieve the case above?

Comment: @BalusC: yep...., you're right...I tried this, and did not work....

Answer (score 0):

If I don't get you wrong, the redirection is triggered by your security constraint.  In that case, after the user has logged in, he/she will be redirected to the original url, i.e. /myApp/internalPage.xhtml?orderId=1234 (with the param)

Comment: Thanks, but I need the original param inclusive in login page.